# Global module with ejbs

Tags: ejb, wildfly, jndi

I deployed a global module with remote ejbs defined, but I can't access them from deployed applications.

Here is the interface:

```
@Remote

public interface ICryptoAPI..



and bean definition:

@Stateless

public class CryptoAPI implements ICryptoAPI ...
```

How can I find jndi name of the ejbs deployed, since default @Ejb cannot find bean? Just to mention, /subsystem=naming:jndi-view() from jboss-cli doesn't print anything about deployed module and there are no errors in wildfly log.

Maybe, it is not possible to define injectable ejbs in global modules?

Answer (score 0):

The [portable JNDI name](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html), an EJB is bound to, depends on how beans are deployed and some configurations (e.g. deployment descriptors).

In addition to the portable JNDI name, JBoss provides access from a remote VM within the `java:jboss/exported` namespace.

For your convenience, JBoss' default logging shows the JNDI names, an EJB is bound to, on console and in the server logfile upon deployment. The logger is `org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment` on `INFO` level.

Example:

```
12:00:00,000 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'MyBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "my-beans.jar" of deployment "my-app.ear"' are as follows:

java:global/my-app/my-beans/MyBean!my.package.MyBeanRemote
java:app/my-beans/MyBean!my.package.MyBeanRemote
java:module/MyBean!my.package.MyBeanRemote
java:jboss/exported/my-app/my-beans/MyBean!my.package.MyBeanRemote
```

For accesing the EJB, you can do a manual JNDI lookup or use the `@EJB` annotations [lookup method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html#lookup()) for injection.

Comment: But I'm deploying EJB bean inside a global module, not a .ear application and doesn't get any pieces of information in the log.

Comment: How are you deploying an EJB as "global module"? Do you mean a JBoss module? This is not a deployment. It's just providing classes, so no EJBs are deployed at all.

Comment: Exactly. Is there a way to register ejb beans inside global jboss module?

Comment: Nope. But why not deploying the "global" EJBs as separate enterprise application?

Comment: That's my intention now, but I wanted to make it part of the server.

Comment: Is there a way to make my application deploy as part of server startup process, without the need to start deployment through cli?